# Updating value with Before Insert Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have the following table structure and planning on update the '`status`' column to 1 whenever the latest dated backup's '`file_size_mb`' is greater than yesterday's '`file_size_mb`'. Everything seems to be executing smoothly but the 'status' is not getting updated.

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `backuplog` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_size_mb` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `StartTime` (`start_time`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Trigger**

```
    delimiter //
    drop trigger backuplog_status_trgr//
    create trigger backuplog_status_trgr
    before insert on backuplog
    for each row 
    begin
    if (
    (Select file_size_mb FROM backuplog 
    WHERE date(start_time)=curdate() 
and SUBSTRING(file_name,1,8)='binfoxxx' 
and DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%H:%i')='01:30')
    >
    (Select file_size_mb FROM backuplog 
WHERE date(start_time)=date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day) 
and SUBSTRING(file_name,1,8)='binfoxxx' 
and  DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%H:%i')='01:30'))
    then
    set NEW.status=1;
    end if;
    end;
    //
    delimiter ;
```

**Sample inserts just so you can test if you want to**

```
insert  into `backuplog`(`id`,`file_name`,`file_size_mb`,`start_time`,`status`) values (1,'binfoxxx_03-02-2021.sql','9236','2021-02-03 01:30:01',NULL),(2,'binfoxxx_04-02-2021.sql','80757','2021-02-04 01:30:01',NULL);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Select * from backuplog;
    
    +----+-------------------------+--------------+---------------------+--------+
    | id | file_name               | file_size_mb | start_time          | status |
    +----+-------------------------+--------------+---------------------+--------+
    |  1 | binfoxxx_03-02-2021.sql |         9236 | 2021-02-03 01:30:01 |   NULL |
    |  2 | binfoxxx_04-02-2021.sql |        80757 | 2021-02-04 01:30:01 |   NULL |
    +----+-------------------------+--------------+---------------------+--------+
```

**Outputs of the subqueries used inside the trigger**

*SUBQUERY:1*

```
Select file_size_mb FROM backuplog 
    WHERE date(start_time)=curdate() 
and SUBSTRING(file_name,1,8)='binfoxxx' 
and DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%H:%i')='01:30';

+--------------+
| file_size_mb |
+--------------+
|        80757 |
+--------------+
```

*SUBQUERY:2*

```
Select file_size_mb FROM backuplog 
WHERE date(start_time)=date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day) 
and SUBSTRING(file_name,1,8)='binfoxxx' 
and  DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%H:%i')='01:30';

+--------------+
| file_size_mb |
+--------------+
|         9236 |
+--------------+
```

Comment: *Everything seems to be executing smoothly but the 'status' is not getting updated.* This means that the condition in `IF` statement is FALSE. If it is TRUE then you will receive an error like 'Cannot update the table which the trigger is defined on'. Totally - your trigger is wrong. Minimal correction - remove the line `update backuplog`, use only `set NEW.status=1;`. Also it is possible in theory that one of subqueries (maybe even both) will return more than one row - this will cause an error too.

Comment: Provide: Complete CREATE TABLE script, some sample data as INSERT INTO script, INSERT INTO statement (which inserts 2 or more rows - at least one which needs in trigger action and another which not) and desired final data state for shown data and statement. With explanations. of course.

Comment: Thank you  for your response. Please see the query above now and tell me what's wrong with it if you can. :)

Comment: Investigate [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=396087390b10afbb80f93e029a86bec5), especially the info stored into `debug` table. You'll see that some debugging INSERTs rows are skipped. This means that according SELECT does not return rows (rowset is empty). This is a reason why your `IF` is FALSE.

Comment: Recommendation: execute each subquery separately and store its output into UDV. Then use these UDVs in IF with COALESCE().